# Force Product-Swift.h to update

Tags: objective-c, swift, integration

I'm using both Swift and Objective-c code in my app.
problem is, sometimes after updating a class thats written in Swift, Then trying to use it from a class written in objective-c, the changes have not updated at the 'Product-Swift.h' file!

Is there any way to force this update manually?

Comment: @RASS Building is not enough

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it!

So the init method was not generated to Product-Swift.h file, here it is:

```
internal init(transitionNavigator : TransitionNavigator,bundleSelected bundle : Bundle) {
```

The problem was the 'TransitionNavigator' file was written in swift too, and once I marked the class with @objc :

```
@objc class TransitionNavigator {
```

It solved it!